# How can I connect a PS3 to two TV/ sound systems in two different rooms?

Tags: ps3, monitor, audio-hardware

Our PS3 sits in our lounge connected to our TV(1080p) via HDMI and our home theatre via the digital optical connection.

I want to be able to use our PS3 in the room directly below our lounge.

I'd like to connect it to another TV(1080i) via HDMI and to a small home audio system (using a 3.5mm stereo plug or RCA plugs). I also have USB speakers I could use.

Ideally I'd like to be able to easily switch between the two TVs without having to unplug/ re-plug any leads. My PS3 is the first generation premium model.

What would be the easiest/ recommended way of going about this?

I live in New Zealand so have limited access to parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Audio-wise, you are in luck, since you wish to use two different connectors and the PS3 [can be instructed to output audio through several connectors](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/settings/audiomulti.html). Simply connect both sound systems to the PS3 at the same time and turn on Audio multi-output and you should be good to go.

Video is another matter, since you only have 1 HDMI connector on the PS3. The only option I see here is to use an HDMI splitter. Be aware that a proper HDMI splitter usually requires additional power to work properly. It should be a box that comes with an additional power supply, like this:
[image: Proper HDMI splitter]

And **not** a simple cable that splits in two, as these typically do not work (and technically, I'm not entirely sure they can work. I've never seen one with positive user reviews):
[image: Bad HDMI splitter]

Comment: I didn't include direct links to product pages as these do not necessarily stand the test of time. Both product images are from products I found on amazon by looking for "HDMI Splitter".

Comment: Thank you Aubergine. I've ordered a powered splitter, it's probably a week away. I'll let you know how it all goes (and give the green tick of course).